# insert using Triggers in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

As i have two tables called buildings and address. i have to insert values to both tables at same time but as column 'id' is auto increment in buildings table after inserting into buildings table 'id' will be generated the same 'id' has to be inserted into 'ref_id' of address table.

so please help me to create triggers for this..

```
CREATE TABLE `buildings` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`client_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`sl_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id,client_id)
)

CREATE TABLE `address` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`ref_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`line1` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`line2` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`city` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`state` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`pincode` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

Comment: Please tell me is there any other way to insert in to two tables...

Comment: Yes, there is: use 2 insert statements with last_insert_id ()

Comment: is it possible to create trigger for this ?

Comment: No, because you cannot pass parameters to a trigger, so it would not know what to insert in the second table.

Comment: can i insert only 'ref_id' from buildings table 'id' others fields as null and update it later..

Comment: What's the point of doing this?